# Do I need to have drawable/xxxhdpi Images in Android?

Tags: android

I know Android sources say "xxxhdpi is only necessary for an appropriate icon size", But should I still specify drawable-xxxhdpi in my project? (for use of Bitmap Images) Or is it safe to just have mdpi through xxhdpi, and have to system scale the image on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many devices including Nexus 6, LG G3 use xxxhdpi icons. So,

1) if you are targetting to those devices

2) if you want to have "your" control over how the icon appears on those devices

If your answer to both the questions above is yes, then you need to have the xxxhdpi version of your icon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should if you want to control how your drawables look on devices that use the resources in this folder.